# Centos httpd 2.4.3 service does not support chkconfig

Tags: apache2, centos, apache

Had to update apache to 2.4.3 on a centos 5.9 server due to a vulnerability.

It is working properly, but I can not figure out a way to make it work with chkconfig (if possible).

I've searched for solutions and tried adding "#chkconfig: - 85 15" into apachectl as all of the websites suggest, but it still says service does not support chkconfig.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file /etc/init.d/httpd to set the run level for Linux to replace the following line:

```
   # chkconfig: - 85 15
```

With this line: # chkconfig: 234 20 80

Start services:-

```
   /sbin/chkconfig httpd on
```